# To Add New Row in lightning datatable While clicking on New Button getting undefined

Tags: javascript, salesforce, salesforce-lightning, lwc

I am trying to add Row when clicking on New Button in lightning Data table.
Created lightning-button in HTML and call the method to js.While trying to click New button getting **Undefined**.
Sample Code:

```
 **Test.html:**

    <template>
    <lightning-card >
    <lightning-button-group>
          <lightning-button label="New" onclick={addRow}></lightning-button>
    </lightning-button-group>
    <lightning-datatable data={strpData} columns={columns} onsave={saveHandleAction}
      draft-values={fldsItemValues} key-field="Id" onrowselection={getSelectedRows}>
         </lightning-datatable>
    </lightning-card >
    </template>
    
**Test.JS:**

import { LightningElement, track, api, wire } from 'lwc';
const columns = [
    {label:'NUMBER', fieldName:'Name' },
    {label: 'Test1', fieldName: 'Test1'}
];
export default class Test extends LightningElement {
@track columns = columns;
@track strpData = [];
addRow() {  
       // this.isShowModal = true;
       console.log('>>>add row>>>');
        const newRow ={'Name':'','Test1':''};
        console.log('>>>new row>>>'+this.newRow);
        this.strpData.push(newRow);
        console.log('strpData ==>>> '+JSON.stringify(strpData));
    }
}
```

Getting console log error:

[image]

Hope someone could give some help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `.push()`. You need to "replace" the entire `strpData` attribute

```
import { LightningElement, track, api, wire } from 'lwc';
const columns = [
    {label:'NUMBER', fieldName:'Name' },
    {label: 'Test1', fieldName: 'Test1'}
];
export default class Test extends LightningElement {
@track columns = columns;
@track strpData = [];
addRow() {  
       // this.isShowModal = true;
       console.log('>>>add row>>>');
        const newRow ={'Name':'','Test1':''}; 
        console.log('>>>new row>>>'+this.newRow);
        this.strpData = [...this.strpData, newRow];
        console.log('strpData ==>>> '+JSON.stringify(strpData));
    }
}
```

[here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/354825/71604)

Answer (score 0):

**newRow** is a const not a class variable just remove **this** from where you are logging it:

```
addRow() {  
   // this.isShowModal = true;
    console.log('>>>add row>>>');
    const newRow ={'Name':'','Test1':''};
    console.log('>>>new row>>>'+newRow);
    this.strpData.push(newRow);
    console.log('strpData ==>>> '+JSON.stringify(strpData));
}
```